# Adding attachment in android using Java Mail

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am trying to add attachments to an email which I send using JavaMail. I can send the email without attachment but I get an error when I try to attach a file.

```
03-28 18:07:36.735: E/SendMail(6703): null
03-28 18:07:36.735: E/SendMail(6703): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 18:07:36.735: E/SendMail(6703):   at com.example.email.GMailSender.addAttachment(GMailSender.java:95)
03-28 18:07:36.735: E/SendMail(6703):   at com.example.email.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:28)
```

Here is the method I use to attach a file.

```
public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  
        message.setContent(_multipart);
    }
```

and I call it in the Main Activity.

```
sender.addAttachment("/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/Photo.jpg");
```

Do you think there is something wrong with the path of the file, if so how can I get the correct path.

Comment: Even if you can't access the file, I wouldn't expect NullPointerException.  Exactly which line is line 95?  Also, note that you can simplify your code by using the [attachFile method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks for responding, I figured it out couple of minutes ago, `message.setContent(_multipart);` was what the problem. I was trying to use it before even declaring it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to attach a file by reading it from your external storage. So, make sure you have the below permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
```